# python 3 - functions exercise download an image (import urllib.request + random)

Tags: python, function

Python 3, functions.

**There is the following exercise:**

In this exercise, we will write code that allows us to
download an image from the web! We will use an external module and understand how to read the documentation of the functions and use them.
We want to write a function that accepts a photo Url and
downloads the photo to your computer.
You can choose any picture you want from the Internet by clicking the right button and selecting "Copy Image Url”.

the image I chose:
https://images.theconversation.com/files/377569/original/file-20210107-17-q20ja9.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=278%2C340%2C4644%2C3098&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip

the wanted name:
"4.jpg"

the given instructions:

1. Write code that selects a random number between 1 and 1000. The number will be the file name (search how to select a random number in python).
2. The image name has to have the right suffix, so concat“.png" to the end of the number you selected (You can also use .jpg, .bmp, etc).
   For example: if the selected number was 2T0, you should have a variable that holds the string: “270.png”.
3. Import module urllib.request: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request
4. Read "how to use the urlretrieve function":
   http://shecodesconnect.com/shecodes_python_blog/urlretrieve_en.php?lang=%27en%27
5. Use the function you read about in order to
   download the image and save it under the name
   you prepared.
6. Run the code you wrote and check the folder where your code is saved if the image was downloaded!

**my code that doesn't work:**

```
import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(https://images.theconversation.com/files/377569/original/file-20210107-17-q20ja9.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=278%2C340%2C4644%2C3098&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip)
html = open(local_filename)
html.close()

headers.items()
headers["content-type"]
image_url="https://images.theconversation.com/files/377569/original/file-20210107-17-q20ja9.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=278%2C340%2C4644%2C3098&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip.jpg"urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=image_url, filename="4.jpg")

import random()
a=random.randint(1,1000)
print(4)
```

Hope you could help, my code doesn't work,  thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the errors, looks like you end up with the below:

```py
import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://images.theconversation.com/files/377569/original/file-20210107-17-q20ja9.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=278%2C340%2C4644%2C3098&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip')
html = open(local_filename)
html.close()

headers.items()
headers["content-type"]
image_url="https://images.theconversation.com/files/377569/original/file-20210107-17-q20ja9.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=278%2C340%2C4644%2C3098&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=image_url, filename="4.jpg")

import random
a=random.randint(1,1000)
print(4)
```

Assuming the code in the question is what were you were able to come up with, that is.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it doesn't download the image to my computer..(just print the number 4 so it doesn't answer the exercise)

Comment: Yes, I have only fixed the errors in the code. You should be able to use this as a template to download the image data from the given url.